# Jquery - text filter to hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jquery to to create a live filter to hide divs on realtime text input. So far I have the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" name="filter" class="filter">
<div class="media">
    <div class="media-body>
        <h4>Apples</h4>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <div class="media-body>
        <h4>Oranges</h4>
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#filter').keyup(function () { 
        var filter = $("#filter").val();
        $('.media').each(function(i, obj) {
            if ($('this > .media-body > h4:contains(filter)').length === 0) {
                $(this).css("display","none");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want this to work so that as soon as someone types an 'o' the apples div is hidden but currently it hides all the divs as soon as anything is typed.

Also how can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LXEDE/1/

Comment: I suppose items should be shown again when someone clears the filter? :)

Comment: Wow! I pop out for lunch and come back to a flurry of answers! Thank-you every one! =D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to properly interpolate the selector string with the actual value of `filter`.
You also have a typo in `$('this > ...`.

Try this code (with some improvements)

```
$('#filter').keyup(function () {

    var filter = this.value.toLowerCase();  // no need to call jQuery here

    $('.media').each(function() {
        /* cache a reference to the current .media (you're using it twice) */
        var _this = $(this);
        var title = _this.find('h4').text().toLowerCase();

        /* 
            title and filter are normalized in lowerCase letters
            for a case insensitive search
         */
        if (title.indexOf(filter) < 0) {
            _this.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks - can this be modified to filter for none sequential words?

Answer (score 8):

Big thanks to everyone who responded to this question - in the end I went with the solution Fabrizio Calderan provided, but have made a few modifications to it that allow for the text filter to search a string for words in any order and to redisplay previously hidden divs if the user deletes what they've typed, I thought I would share this modified solution with you:

```
    $('#filter').keyup(function () {
        var filter_array = new Array();
        var filter = this.value.toLowerCase();  // no need to call jQuery here

        filter_array = filter.split(' '); // split the user input at the spaces

        var arrayLength = filter_array.length; // Get the length of the filter array

        $('.media').each(function() {
            /* cache a reference to the current .media (you're using it twice) */
            var _this = $(this);
            var title = _this.find('h4').text().toLowerCase();

            /* 
                title and filter are normalized in lowerCase letters
                for a case insensitive search
             */

            var hidden = 0; // Set a flag to see if a div was hidden

            // Loop through all the words in the array and hide the div if found
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                 if (title.indexOf(filter_array[i]) < 0) {
                    _this.hide();
                    hidden = 1;
                }
            }
            // If the flag hasn't been tripped show the div
            if (hidden == 0)  {
               _this.show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

var $medias = $('.media'),
    $h4s = $medias.find('> .media-body > h4');
$('#filter').keyup(function () {
    var filter = this.value,
        regex;
    if (filter) {
        regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(this.value), 'i')
        var $found = $h4s.filter(function () {
            return regex.test($(this).text())
        }).closest('.media').show();
        $medias.not($found).hide()
    } else {
        $medias.show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LXEDE/)

Answer (score 1):

Modified the answer to this

```
    var filter = this.value.toLowerCase();  // no need to call jQuery here

    $('.device').each(function() {
        /* cache a reference to the current .device (you're using it twice) */
        var _this = $(this);
        var title = _this.find('h3').text().toLowerCase();

        /* 
            title and filter are normalized in lowerCase letters
            for a case insensitive search
         */
        if (title.indexOf(filter) < 0) {
            _this.hide();
        }
        else if(filter == ""){
            _this.show();
        }
        else{
            _this.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if ($('.media-body > h4:contains('+filter+')',this).length  === 0) {
        $(this).css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
if ($('this > .media-body > h4:contains(filter)').length === 0) {
```

You should do like this:

```
if ($(this).find(' > .media-body > h4:contains('+filter+')').length === 0) {
```

Or like this:

```
if ($(' > .media-body > h4:contains('+filter+')', this).length === 0) {
```

Comment: Din't you see the answers above?

Comment: First 2 answers probably above yours and next 2 after yours!

Comment: I don't think that. I'm noticing mainly to $('this > is wrong but $(this) should be done.

Comment: You were missing `+ filter +` too!

Comment: that's updated... but my main suggestion to use $(this)... not $('this>..)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)** as well as concatenate your `filter` variable using `+`, so use:

```
if ($(this).children('.media-body > h4:contains(' + filter +')').length === 0) {
    $(this).css("display","none");
}
```

instead of:

```
if ($('this > .media-body > h4:contains(filter)').length === 0) {
    $(this).css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LXxQb/)

```
$('#filter').keyup(function () { 
    var filter = $("#filter").val();
    $('.media').each(function() {
        $(this).find("h4:not(:contains('" + filter + "'))").hide();
        $(this).find("h4:contains('" + filter + "')").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this code to:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function () {  

    // create a pattern to match against, in this one
    // we're only matching words which start with the 
    // value in #filter, case-insensitive

    var pattern = new RegExp('^' + this.value.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"), 'i');

    // hide all h4's within div.media, then filter
    $('div.media h4').hide().filter(function() {

        // only return h4's which match our pattern
        return !!$(this).text().match(pattern);

    }).show(); // show h4's which matched the pattern

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HB5d/29/)

Credit to **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168484/javascript-syntax-error-invalid-regular-expression#16168723)** for the expression to escape special characters in the value.

Comment: You're not escaping `this.value` so that it can be used in regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks @Jack - coincidently I've used a pattern from one of your answers on another question, I feel a bit cheap. Hopefully my upvote will suffice :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 $('#filter').keyup(function () {
            var filter = this.value.toLowerCase();
            $('.media').each(function () {
                var _this = $(this);
                var title = _this.find('h1').text().toLowerCase();

                if (title.indexOf(filter) < 0) {
                    _this.hide();
                }
                if (title.indexOf(filter) == 0) {
                    _this.show();
                }
            });
        });
```